# How to get Vim to never insert escape codes

Tags: vim, macvim

If I am in insert mode and hit C-l (which clears my search in normal mode), Vim inserts ^L into the buffer. I never want this behavior. How do I disable it? I don't want to mapi every possible command, I just don't want garbage inserted every time I make a mistake.

Comment: Why should you treat this any different than any other typo?  Either improve your typing so you don't make the typos or correct the typos when you make them.

Comment: ^L is not "garbage", it's a perfectly legitimate ASCII character.

Comment: As you describe yourself, that entry means two different things in two different modes.  How do you expect vim to understand what you want?  In fact, think about it this way -- if vim had such a feature, why wouldn't it also have a feature called "correct my code"?  Where does this kind of concierge service functionality end?

Comment: If I type Command+J the buffer is inserted with "<D-j>" When would anyone ever want that?

Comment: That character must map to some ASCII value (or extended ASCII value) - I don't know, I don't do Macs.  If you were editing a file that where declaring such codes makes sense, it would be useful then.   A more practical example is control-M.  There are lots of cases where you want to insert such a sequence in the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems with a particular Ctrl combination in insert mode, you can always turn it off:
`:imap ^L <Nop>` Here Nop is "no operation".

If it's frustrating you, I'd recommend turning it off while trying stop the habit. It probably acts as some kind of reinforcement every time you see the ^L and think "D'oh I've done that again".

Having said that, in insert mode there are lots of *really* useful Ctrl combination that you can use to do useful operations with, so I wouldn't recommend turning them all off.

Ctrl-L (and Ctrl-Z for that matter), are really useful keys to remap to something *you* find useful. They're really only used when you make insert mode the default mode, rather than normal mode - see `:h insertmode`

Ctrl-L is also really nice to remap as it's easy to press being on the home row and it remapping it shouldn't interfere with anything.

Using it for something that you find useful will build up muscle memory and should stop you pressing it by accident.

Comment: `Ctrl-L` redraws the screen by default.  If you're going to remap this, I highly suggest adding a redraw to the end of your mapping.

Comment: Ctrl-L redraws in normal mode, but not in insert mode. The suggestion I made is to use Ctrl-L and Ctrl-Z as insert mode mappings.

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you

```
:inoremap <C-l> <C-o><C-l>
```

and be a happy chappy? C-o temporarily 'suspends' insert mode, so you can do 'normal mode' command without actually leaving insert mode.

Highly underrated

```
:he <C-o>
```

:wq